# Set selected value for a dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working in an angularjs app, and I having a hard time trying to set the selected value in a select tag.

Notice, the 2nd option has the `selected="selected"`

I tried all the solutions posted, like set the doc type t html5, add *`autocomplete=off`*, add a name to the form tag. And nothing seems to work. Any idea how to achieve that.

This is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/20cw7eqe/ and works fine there.

But it does not work on FF or Chrome. BTW, Im using bootstrap.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xc8Qrcr0AN4I2U0chbye?p=preview

There you can see 2 different examples of `select` tag, for different models. You can use the one that is more similar to your case.

Just set in your controller the value you want to be selected. `ng-model` will make the rest.

I have edited the plunker so you can se how ng-selected works. This was the code included:

```
<select required="true" ng-model="selected3">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options2" ng-selected="option == 'second'" >{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ignacio . Both examples worked fine, for some reason not in my case.

Maybe is due I'm using ngDialog, and the select is in that pop up dialog. But futher that, the question is, why selected="selected" did not work.

Comment: Could you build a better fiddle, using an ng-repeat? I believe that you copied what angularjs rendered after compiling ng-repeat.

Comment: You're right.

I'm copying the angular rendered. I'm using the ng-selected in the way you pointed out. So, as you can see in my 2nd option the angular rendered correct adding the selected="selected". But for some strange reason, that attribute is not respected.

Comment: could you build a plunker reproducing the error exactly as you are telling?